# What is a 'stud defender' in baseball?

Tags: baseball, terminology

I found an expression 'stud defender' in [this article about the shift in MLB](https://www.cbssports.com/mlb/news/mlb-set-to-implement-rule-changes-for-2023-including-a-pitch-clock-per-report/)

> The team must designate two infielders for each side of second base and they cannot switch (for example, a team can't have a stud defender move back and forth based upon the handedness of the hitter).

What does a *stud defender* mean exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think rather than being a set phrase or baseball jargon, it's using "stud" to mean a fantastic player.  You can read this phrase as "stellar infielder".

If you have an A++ infielder and several others of average ability, you can't move the standout from SS to 2B as the batters change to cover the changes in probability of which side the ball is likely to arrive.